# For subspaces $S,U,W$ of a $K$-vector space, prove $S\cap\langle U\cup W\rangle=\langle\langle S\cap U\rangle\cup\langle S\cap W\rangle\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

I wasn't sure on how to prove this. I wanted to do this by containment. So suppose that $u = \{u_1, \dots , u_n\}$ was a generating set for $U$ and $w =\{w_1, \dots, w_m\}$ is a generating set for $W$. Then we have that $x = \{u_1, \dots, u_n, w_1, \dots, w_m \}$ is a generating set for $U \cup W$. Now I'm a bit stuck on what to really do next.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it: I'm asking  $S \ \cap <U \cup W> = <<S \cap U> \cup <S \cap W>>$ where $<X>$ is the subspace generated by $X$

Comment: Instead of writing $S\cap<U\cup W>=<<S\cap U>\cup<S\cap W>>$, you should write $S\cap\langle U\cup W\rangle=\langle\langle S\cap U\rangle\cup\langle S\cap W\rangle\rangle$.$\vphantom{\frac\sum\sum}$  I edited the question accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you, I didn't know the command for it.

Comment: @Matthew : Google "LaTeX symbols" and you can find things like this. (This is not LaTeX, of course, but MathJax.  But the mathematical notation is coded in the same way.) ${}\qquad{}$